# Array value label?

Tags: php, arrays, magento, echo

i have an array (Car, SUV, Truck, Bike) that's used in a form. when the option is selected the **value** is saved to the customers account in database. **Value** is the array position (eg: 0, 1, 2, 3).

I want this info to be displayed on another page in a table using **php** as i'm using **magento**. Currently it only displays the database saved value (0,1,2,3), but i want it to show as ((Car, SUV, Truck, Bike). How do i do this?

i need a way to make it know that 0=Car, 1=SUV, 2=Truck, 3=Bike)

heres what the table looks like now:
[image]

The make column represents the vehicle manufacturer (toyota, honda, etc)and type represents (car, bike, suv)

Please help!

Comment: Is this a standard Magento model structure? If not, you will probably need to join the table that holds the string values

Comment: Are the actual names for the vehicle makes and types already in separate database tables?

Comment: @JohnMcMahon no there not. i have them in 2 option array, vtype and vmake in my data.php file in my module folder. in the form it shows correctly, in the backend form it shows correctly also, but in the table it shows the value instead of the name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the table field `type` [an enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) that matches the array you specified.

**More Details**

An ENUM data type is an array that maps a key to a value.  If you change the column `type` to an enumeration, then your Database will display an human readable value instead of a number (e.g., Car, SUV, Truck, Bike).

Also, you can interact with the enum using the Key or the Value so you shouldn't have to change your current implementation.

Comment: could you elaborate please?